# Android warning and information messages

Tags: android, android-studio

I try to understand warning and information message when I run my android app.

The first Warning that I get is :

```
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.myphoceenapp.mobile-1/lib/x86
```

It's appear two times in a row.

My second Warning is :

```
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
```

Finally I have two OpendGLRenderer message in row with different tid :

```
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                               [ 06-06 10:45:16.066 14878:14878 D/         ]
                                               HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb3fd8cf0, tid 14878


                                               [ 06-06 10:45:16.089 14878:14903 D/         ]
                                               HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb3fd8cc0, tid 14903
```

For this message I think I am creating two contexts maybe ?

Thanks.